# MySQL inserting rows with 0 value in primary key

Tags: mysql

MySQL (v5.41) on Ubuntu is inserting rows with primary key value as 0.

Below is the MySQL table data.

```
mysql> select id from keywords where text_id = 72;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  0 |
|  0 |
+----+

| keywords | CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `to_user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

+--------+---------------------------------

Comment: Please include the output of `show create table keywords;`

Comment: +1 for El Yobo. I think the field text_id is NOT a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the primary key column to `AUTO INCREMENT` also.

Like

```
CREATE TABLE table (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the field id as AUTOINCREMENT